# Access to the path is denied with user with several domains

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0, iis-6, impersonation

We have a web application that uploads a file to a remote server, specifically a folder within the virtual folder (ie. c:\inetpub\MyWebApp\UploadedFiles). Our domain is MYDOMAIN.

In IIS, `Anonymous Authentication` and `Forms Authentication` are set to `Disabled` while `ASP.Net Impersonation` and `Windows Authentication` are set to `Enabled`. The app pool is `ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated`.

With users in our domain, everything works fine. So Bob (MYDOMAIN\Bob) logs on to the laptop and the website with the same credentials (MYDOMAIN\Bob).

The problem is with a user outside of the domain. Joe logs on to their box with HISDOMAIN\Joe, but then logs on to the website with a user in our domain (MYDOMAIN\Rick). Joe isn't part of MYDOMAIN, so he's using Rick's until he gets his userid.

With the included IIS configuration, Joe was able to upload files, but now he's getting the error and I'm not exactly sure what else to do.

In the meantime, I added MYDOMAIN\Rick to folder 'UploadedFiles' and gave him full access, so it's now working. But I'd like to know why this is happening.

Thanks.

Comment: How does Joe log on to the website?

Comment: Using **MYDOMAIN\Rick** since Joe still hasn't received a userid for **MYDOMAIN**, but he logged on to his laptop using **HISDOMAIN\Joe**.